# Docker output not showing in logs for ubuntu but showing up for debian

Tags: docker, logging, output, airflow

When I make a simple Dockerfile and script like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY my.sh
ENTRYPOINT my.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
printf hello
```

and then run it with `docker run my-img` I see `hello` printed.

When I run this in Airflow with `DockerOperator`, even with `tty=True`, the logs don't show the `hello`.

If I switch the parent image to `FROM debian` the output shows up as expected.

Why is this? What is the difference between the `ubuntu` and `debian` images that causes the strange output behavior? How can I make the output from `ubuntu` also show up in Airflow logs?